# What does swing exactly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could someone explain to me what swing means in this sentence?

> "... the party was swinging ..."

I've checked a dictionary and the word swing has a lot of meanings...

Comment: http://www.oldielyrics.com/lyrics/the_chad_mitchell_trio/hang_on_the_bell_nellie.html

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ellafitzgerald/itdontmeanathingifitaintgotthatswing.html

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/johnnycash/swinglowsweetchariot.html

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/franksinatra/swingingonastar.html

Answer (score 1):

Sense 3 of the OED's adjective - ***swinging*** begins by relating it first to rhythmic movement, then to music (a and b).

Sense 3c follows on from there **and it is the one that you want**:

> c. Uninhibited, ignoring conventions; lively and up to date: applied
>   to persons, places ( swinging London), etc., and spec. to the 1960s (
>   swinging Sixties). Also, as a general term of approval: fine,
>   splendid, ‘great’ (temporarily contrasted with dodgy). colloq.
>
> 1958   Publ. Amer. Dial. Soc. xxx. 47   Swingin', the highest term of
>   approval. May be applied to anything a jazzman likes, or any person.
>
> 1959   Manch. Guardian 25 June 8/7   [She] informed him that she wants
>   a large place ‘in a swinging part of town’..so he is looking around in
>   Chelsea and Knightsbridge.
>
> 1962   J. Baldwin Another Country (1963) ii. iii. 299   ‘You feeling
>   all right?’.. ‘He's going to feel just swinging.’
>
> 1964   N. Vaughan in T.V. World 24 Sept. 48   When people ask me how I
>   feel about the months ahead, I tell them: ‘Sometimes it's a bit dodgy,
>   but most of the time it's swinging!’
>
> 1965   Weekend Tel. 16 Apr. p. xii/2   Diana Vreeland..editor of
>   Vogue..has said simply ‘London is the most swinging city in the world
>   at the moment’.
>
> > 1967   Listener 19 Jan. 107/1   He does not fit into the Zeitgeist of
> >     the swinging 'sixties.
>
> 1980   M. Sellers Leonardo & Others x. 56   Zuleika lived life to the
>   full. She was a product of the swinging sixties.
>
> 1982   S. Brett Murder Unprompted v. 51   The British film
>   industry..was committed to making zany films about Swinging London.

And finally in sense d - it takes on a sexual connotation:

> ```
> d. Of or relating to a person who engages in promiscuous sexual activity (esp. group sex or the swapping of sexual partners). slang.
> ```
>
> 1964   W. & J. Breedlove Swap Clubs ii. 43   A ‘swinging couple’.
>
> 1978   Bulletin (Sydney)  11 Apr. 6/2   ‘Swinging couples’ are no
>   longer addicted to square dancing but to the less innocuous pastime of
>   wife-swapping.

Answer (score 0):

***[To swing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swing)***:

> - [I] informal - to be ​exciting and ​enjoyable:
>
>   - *You need ​music to make a ​party swing.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)